# Accepting to Join AWS Organization with already existing account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a free account with AWS which I created some machines and services on it. Now I got an invitation to join my friend aws organization.

I have a question accepting this invitation and being part of this organization. According to AWS, an AWS account can be a member of only one organization at a time.

Based on this after accepting the invitation:

- Will this affect my current account and my EC2s?
- How can access multiple organizations?

  - Should I create multiple accounts.

Comment: I do not understand your question about accessing multiple organizations. What is your goal?

Comment: @Greg The purpose if I am working for multiple projects with different organizations,  Do I need to have an account associated with each of these organizations and I can not have one consolidate all of them and I can switch between them. Is that correct?

Comment: A single account cannot belong to multiple organizations. If you need accounts under multiple organizations, you would need to use multiple accounts. You can switch between accounts by signing out and signing back in. Or you can switch between accounts using cross account IAM roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining and leaving an organization will have no effect on the EC2 instances or other resources in the account.

There are two kinds of organizations. Consolidated Billing and Full Features.

In a Consolidated Billing organization, the master account pays for all the member accounts (like yours) in the organization. The master account can also see billing details (like service consumption) for all member accounts. However, the master account has no access to the resources in the member accounts.

In a Full Features organization, the master account pays the bills (like a Consolidated Billing organization) but also has administrative access to the member accounts via a cross-account IAM role. The master account can use this role to gain full administrative access to all resources in the member account.

Additionally, a Full Features organization can apply Service Control Policies to member accounts that restrict that accounts access to AWS services and APIs.

A member account can belong to only one organization at a time. The member account can leave an organization at any time. The master account can remove member accounts from the organization at any time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am worrying about my EC2 and resources in my stand alone account that I have before joining the organization.@Greg